# Node.js sequelize deadlock issue

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, deadlock

I am currently developing a service using nodejs, sequelize, mysql and reactjs.

The following code creates a reply for an article.

```
module.exports.reply = async ({
  userId,
  postId,
  text
}) => {
  const t1 = await orm.transaction({
    isolationLevel: orm.Transaction.ISOLATION_LEVELS.SERIALIZABLE
  });

  try {
    let retData = { code: 0, data: {}};

    const reply = await replyModel.findOne({
      where: {
        userId: userId,
        postId: postId
      },
      lock: t1.LOCK.UPDATE,
      transaction: t1
    });

    if (reply == null) {
      await replyModel.create({
        postId: postId,
        text: text
      }, {transaction: t1});
    }

    retData.code = 200;

    await t1.commit();

    return retData;
  } catch (err) {
    await t1.rollback();

    throw err;
  }
}
```

The code above is a POST request to create a reply for an article.

If I clicked reply button 5~10 times continuously, then deadlock occurs.

To avoid deadlock I hided the button if it was clicked.

However, is there any other way to avoid deadlock on server side when the reply request happen multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

Blocking/disabling the posting button *(and maybe also displaying a "loading" symbol)* until the reply is posted seems like a good UX practice.

If you wanted to provide your users with the ability to update a single DB row simultaneously (ex. many users posting updates for the same item at the same time), then I would suggest using job queues (like [BullMQ](https://github.com/taskforcesh/bullmq)) to apply those updates sequentially.